# pyKML: lxml.ettree.XMLSyntaxError: Failed to parse QName , line, column

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, pykml

```
from pykml import parser
from os import path
import pandas as pd

kml_file = path.join( r'file.kml')

with open(kml_file) as f:
    doc = parser.parse(f)
```

Trying to make this one working in python and pyKML, but it's failing  to parse Qname in line and column

ex:lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Failed to parse QName ':anonymous', line 32447, column 17

Comment: You probably have whitespace after the `anonymous:` namespace prefix in a start tag. Something like `<anonymous: x>...</anonymous:x>` instead of `<anonymous:x>...</anonymous:x>`. We could verify this if you showed us line 32447.

Comment: <LineString>
     <tessellate>1</tessellate>
     <:anonymous />          3447
     <coordinates>8.16000833333333,44.07492,0

so i have to delete the whitespace only here right?

Comment: The error is similar to what I guessed but not exactly the same. `<:anonymous />` is not a valid (self-closing) element. There has to be a prefix before the colon. Perhaps you can just remove the colon.